# iPad: UITableView Within UIView Covers Elements When Scrolled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, uiscrollview

I am attempting to place scroll view within a UIView that is smaller than the entire iPad screen. I simply add the scroll view as a subview of the UIView and it appears just fine, however when I scroll it, it moves outside of the bounds of that UIView effectively covering up any UI elements that are placed above it.

Is there some way to set the bounds of that scroll view to be the frame of the UIView?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [clipToBounds](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW60) to YES on the UIView that is holding the scroll view.